# Why build executor status showing two jobs for one pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a groovy pipeline script for a build job, so in jenkins pipeline is like,

```
node
{
  git url : 'myurl.git'
  load 'mydir/myfile.groovy'
}
```

Its working well as expected. but in build executor status, It is showing it as two jobs running.

- Why it is showing one job as two jobs with same name ?.
- Is there something which i have missed to tell something to jenkins for pipeline job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a better documentation source than [this README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) (issue [JENKINS-35710](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35710) also has some information), but the short of it is the Groovy pipeline executes on master (on a flyweight executor) while `node` blocks run on an allocated executor.

Here is a relevant snippet taken from the linked documentation:

> [...]
>
> Why are there two executors consumed by one Pipeline build?
>
> - Every Pipeline build itself runs on the master, using a flyweight executor — an uncounted slot that is assumed to not take any significant computational power.
> - This executor represents the actual Groovy script, which is almost always idle, waiting for a step to complete.
> - Flyweight executors are always available.