# How does Jenkins execute code on remote slaves?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a piece of code to list all files in the `/tmp` directory on two nodes, like so (scripted syntax):

```groovy
stage('Demo') {
    node('node1') {
        println new File('/tmp/').listFiles().toList()
    }

    node('node2') {
        println new File('/tmp/').listFiles().toList()
    }
}
```

However, the results from both nodes are identical. It looks like the code is executed on the master, only the println function is executed on the 2 nodes.

The question is: is it true? and if so, how do I know if the code is executed on master or slaves?

Comment: Pipeline code is executed on `master`. I have written a couple answer that touch on this (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778166/calling-shell-commands-in-groovy-script-used-in-jenkins-pipeline/47796765#47796765) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904939/why-build-executor-status-showing-two-jobs-for-one-pipeline-job/50910850#50910850)).

Comment: @mkobit: According to those 2 links, shouldn't the code blocks inside `node` be executed on agents?

Comment: any of the Jenkins steps that use the `node` context will execute on those agents. For example, a `sh 'ls -1 /tmp/`' would run the `ls -1 /tmp/` command on that agent. But, the actual Groovy `sh` method and JVM code execute on the Jenkins master. All of the Groovy inside of a Jenkins pipeline is executed on the master. Hence why `new File('/tmp')` executes on the master rather than the agent. Hopefully, that does not add more confusion.

Comment: @mkobit: Please make your comment an answer so that I can mark this question as solved. If you could, please expand the answer on how to know if a step requires Jenkins context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Jenkins steps that use the `node` context will execute on those agents (from the `node` blocks). For example, a `sh 'ls -1 /tmp/'` would run the `ls -1 /tmp/ command` on that agent that is in the block. But, the actual Groovy `sh` method and JVM code execute on the Jenkins master.

All of the Groovy inside of a Jenkins pipeline is executed on the master in a special source-transformed fashion from the [*Pipeline Groovy Plugin*](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin). Hence, why `new File('/tmp')` executes on the master rather than the agent. If you were running your pipeline using the security sandbox, you would get a security exception because `new File` by default is disallowed. In fact, any of the normal JVM style methods are disallowed. For example, wouldn't it be terrible if a pipeline could call `System.exit(0)` and shut down Jenkins for all of the users?

Similar questions:

- [Calling shell commands in groovy script, used in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47778166/627727)
- [Why build executor status showing two jobs for one pipeline job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50904939/627727)

Answer (score 3):

Pipeline DSL context runs on master node even that your write `node('someAgentName')` in your pipeline. `new File` will work only on master.

But you can read data from file via [sh()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-sh-%20shell%20script). Something like:

```
def list = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ls').trim()
```